# How can I SELECT all jobs from jobs table and the MAXIMUM job bid from bids table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

jobs:

jobID, col1, col2

and bids:

bidID, jobID, bid, status

Any job can have an unlimited number of bids made against it.

I want to display the results in a table client side showing all job details, along with the maximum bid  for each job and that bid's status.

I seem to be able to get as far as displaying the max bid, but not that bid's corresponding status.

Thanks for any help!

```
SELECT jobs.jobID as jobID, jobs.col1 as col1, jobs.col2 as col2, 
MAX(bids.bid) as bid, bids.status as status
FROM jobs
JOIN bids on jobs.jobID = bids.jobID
GROUP BY jobID
ORDER BY bid desc;
```

Comment: You're mixing jobbids and bids. Or are those two distinct tables?

Comment: Maybe try and use more distinctive names, at a glance that is a confusing query

Comment: Thank you Shomz. There are only two tables (jobs and bids). I was indeed mixing bids and jobbids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT j.*, MAX(b.bid) as bid,
       substring_index(group_concat(jb.status order by b.bid desc), ',', 1) as status
FROM jobs j left join
     jobbids jb
     on j.jobID = jb.jobID left join
     bids b
     on jb.bidId = b.bidId
GROUP BY j.jobId
ORDER BY bid desc;
```

I made the following changes:

- You want all rows in `jobs`, so I changed the `join`s to `left join`.
- You reference a `bids` table, so I added it in.
- I added logic to get the last status

Note:  this assumes that the number of bids is not too large. MySQL has a (configurable) maximum size for the string produced by `group_concat()`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon,

I made a typo in my original post (now corrected). There are only two tables. Jobs and bids.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this solution scales horrendously badly?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following query:-

```
SELECT jobs.jobID as jobID, jobs.col1 as col1, jobs.col2 as col2, 
MAX(bids.bid) as bid, bids.status as status
FROM jobs
JOIN bids on jobs.jobID = bids.jobID
GROUP BY jobID, status
ORDER BY bid desc;
```

Now try edited version.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This is actually the query I am using. My original post has an error in it. Will change now.

The problem with the above query is that it will not select the job status which is part of the same record as the max bid from the bids table.

Answer (score 0):

The stock answer, is a an uncorellated subquery, as described in the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

```
SELECT j.*
     , x.* 
  FROM bids x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT jobID,MAX(bid) max_bid FROM bid GROUP BY jobID ) y 
    ON y.jobID = x.jobID
   AND y.max_bid = x.bid
  JOIN jobs j
    ON j.jobID = x.jobID;
```

Comment: While your solution may or may not solve the issue, please add some explanation on what your code is doing